# Выпадающий/Скрывающийся элемент для каждой строки(Angular 4)

Tags: html, вёрстка, angular4, dropdown

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
  <div>Фото</div>
  <div>{{ hotel.name }}</div>
  <div><button (click)="changeIsShohToTrue()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button></div>

  <div *ngIf="isShow">Доп. информация</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо показывать/скрывать дополнительный div при нажатии на кнопку

Проблема: при нажатии на кнопку будут открываться все дополнительные div - как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
    <div>Фото</div>
    <div>{{ hotel.name }}</div>
    <div><button (click)="changeIsShohToTrue(hotel)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button></div>

    <div *ngIf="hotel.expand">Доп. информация {{hotel.info}}</div>
  </div>
```

hotel.cmponent.ts:

```
export class HotelComponent {
  title = 'app';
  hotels = [
    {name: 'Hotel1', info: 'Hotel1 info'},
    {name: 'Hotel2', info: 'Hotel2 info'},
    {name: 'Hotel3', info: 'Hotel3 info'}

  ];
  prevHotel: any;

  changeIsShohToTrue(hotel) {
    if (this.prevHotel && this.prevHotel.expand && this.prevHotel !== hotel) {
      this.prevHotel.expand = false;
    }
    hotel.expand = !hotel.expand;
    this.prevHotel = hotel;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать `isShow` свойством объекта `hotel`.

Также в функции `changeIsShohToTrue` менять свойство `isShow` у объекта `hotel`.

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
  <div>Фото</div>
  <div>{{ hotel.name }}</div>
  <div><button (click)="changeIsShohToTrue(hotel)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button></div>

  <div *ngIf="hotel.isShow">Доп. информация</div>
</div>
```